# How can i send my PointCloud sensor data topic to costmap2d node?

Tags: ros

I installed costmap2d_ros package and all the other depedencides.

But i can not find any subscriber in costmap_2d sources which receives my lidar sensor data topic.
Also I can not find a publisher which publishes topic named "voxel_grid"

Do i need to install other packages? or am i just missing some other process or packages.

Is that possible to make costmap only with costmap2d_ros packages?

sorry for my bad english.

If you need any more informations of my environments, please ask me. I'd be right back ASAP

In rqt_graph , voxel_visualizer node and costmap2d node have no any connection.

voxel_visualizer node is subscribing the topic named "voxel_grid" , but I can not find any publisher publishing topic named "voxel_grid" within the whole sources in costmap_2d packages.

Comment: use `rosnode info <node_name>` to get more info about the topic names and which data type they should be.

Comment: I think you usethis [navigation](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation) to set up your stack properly. You might be missing some nodes

Answer (score 0):

[move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base) package is responsible for transforming lidar, pointcloud etc data to costmap_2d as obstacles both in [local](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/blob/master/turtlebot3_navigation/param/local_costmap_params.yaml) and [global](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/blob/master/turtlebot3_navigation/param/global_costmap_params.yaml) [or both](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/blob/master/turtlebot3_navigation/param/costmap_common_params_burger.yaml) costmaps depending on how you configure it and is launched by [move_base](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/blob/master/turtlebot3_navigation/launch/move_base.launch).

So correct way would be to setup your robot following [official navigation stack tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation). And it has some dependencies on robot capabilities.

> Is that possible to make costmap only with costmap2d_ros packages?

I'm not familiar with it so I can't answer. But it doesn't seem easy to do